# Объединить 2 массива в один

Tags: javascript

как объединить их в `this.bufArr`, чтобы ключами были буквы из `leftArray`
а значение брались по букве из `letterArray` Пытался пушом но не получалось

```js
lettersArr.forEach((el) => {
  this.bufArr.push({
    leftArray[el]: lettersArr[el]
  });
  console.log(this.bufArr);
});
```

[image: 2 массива]

Comment: А где желаемый результат на ТАКИХ исходных?

Comment: У вас ведь leftArray это массив. У него нет строковых ключей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял о чем речь:

```js
let leftArray = ["M", "B", "H", "K", "T", "A"];
let lettersArray = {
  M: 1,
  B: 2,
  H: 3,
  K: 4,
  T: 5,
  A: 6
};
let bufferObj = {};

leftArray.forEach((letter) => {
  bufferObj[letter] = lettersArray[letter];
});

console.log(bufferObj);
```

Но вообще задача непонятна. Думаю она решается изящнее.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const leftArray = ["п", "е", "ч", "е", "н", "ь", "к", "и"], 
      letterActuallyNotArray = { е:12, к:78, и:14, н:8, п:61, ч:15, ь:37 };
const bufAlsoNotArr = leftArray.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c] = letterActuallyNotArray[c]; 
  return r; 
}, {}); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(bufAlsoNotArr));
```